# How to make a function that declares variables? (JS)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hy!

I am doing the first exercises from the book "Exercises for Programmers: 57 Challenges to Develop Your Coding Skills" by Brian P. Hogan and this requires some DOM manipulation.

In this specific case, I have a form and I want to get and declare in the js file the form, the inputs of the form and a div. I would usually do:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
const noun = document.getElementById('noun');
const verb = document.getElementById('verb');
const adverb = document.getElementById('adverb');
const result = document.getElementById('result');
```

But I want to make a function similar to this:

```
function getDomElementById(element) {
  const element = document.getElementById(`${element}`);
}
```

and in Chrome I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'element' has already been declared

This function should get the element by its id and declare it.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `element` is the parameter name, you can't also use it as a `const`.

Comment: It makes no sense to have a function declare variables for the outside. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to solve?

Comment: remove `const` and you're good to go

Comment: @nickzoum not exactly - `element` still shadows the outer `element`, so assignment wouldn't do anything for the outer variable. The outer variable also has `const`, so even without the name shadowing you cannot assign it. Then even if the binding is mutable, it's just *strange* to have a function do assignments in the outer scope. So, I wouldn't say "good" but it can work as in - not throw errors. I'm not convinced it's "good" as in "idea" or "design".

Comment: @VLAZ I want to make a function that declares a variable with an Element object representing the element whose id property is the argument of the function.
The output of that function(myForm) should be a variable: myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

Comment: That sounds like a particular *solution* you are trying to implement. Why would you need such a function? It's exceedingly rare to *need* a function to mess with the global state and just do assignments. If a function only does an assignment, it's best practice to remove the global mutation from it and make it return whatever it would otherwise assign. So, this means you'd have `function getDomElementById(element) { return document.getElementById(`${element}`); }` which means it's just `document.getElementById(element)` with extra steps.

Comment: @VLAZ somebody told me once that if you do the same thing several times then probably you can make a function that can do that for you.
So I was trying to implement that to make my code shorter.
But I see that in this specific case this is not the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDomElementById(element) {
  const element = document.getElementById(`${element}`);
}
```

Here you redeclared variable named `element`.
`const element` is wrong.
Please rename this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an object for the elements, like

```
const elements = {
    myForm: document.getElementById('myForm'),
    noun: document.getElementById('noun'),
    // ...
}
```

or take a dynalic approach with an array of ids and an object with the ids as keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can not create variable like that but you can use object

```
let obj = {};

const getDomElementById = (element) => {
  obj = {
    ...obj,
    [element]: document.getElementById(`${element}`),
  }
}
```

> How to use :  getDomElementById('myForm');

get DOMs by

> obj.myForm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write less code, give the function a shorter name and have it return the selection:

```
const getEl = function( id ) {
  return document.getElementById( `${ id }` );
};
const myForm = getEl('myForm');
const noun = getEl('noun');
const verb = getEl('verb');
```

The problem with having the function assign to variables on the outside, is:

1) The code code is not shorter than the original that uses `document.getElementById()` directly. And you'll have to use an object to refer to the elements using a string like `'myForm'`. So you'll end up having to use values.myForm everywhere you want to use it.

```
const values = {
  myForm: null,
  noun: null,
  verb: null
};
function getDomElementById( id ) {
  values[ id ] = document.getElementById(`${ id }`);
}
getDomElementById( 'myForm' );
getDomElementById( 'noun' );
getDomElementById( 'verb' );
```

2) Having the function overwrite values on the outside can lead to annoying bugs, where you are looking for which function has overwritten the variable at what time.

3) Soon you'll learn about `.querySelectorAll()`, which is similar to `.getElementById()`, but also allows classes and complex CSS selectors.
If you're still using your function then, you'd have to add another parameter to represent the name:

```
const values = {
  myForm: null,
  noun: null,
  verb: null
};
function getDomElements( name, selector ) {
  value[ name ] = document.querySelectorAll(`${ selector }`);
}
getDomElements( 'myForm', 'section.validation-form > .myForm' );
getDomElements( 'noun', 'section.validation-form > .noun' );
getDomElements( 'verb', 'section.validation-form > #verb.active' );
```

Once I arrived at the point I had the above code, I just switched back to the beginning and removed the function altogether because I was just making the code longer and less easy to read for almost no other advantage.

```
const myForm = document.querySelector( 'section.validation-form > .myForm' );
const noun = document.querySelector( 'section.validation-form > .noun' );
const verb = document.querySelector( 'section.validation-form > #verb.active' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer!